# How to use polymorphic associations in a secured way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, polymorphic-associations, brakeman

I have the following code which an object (`rmodal`) is created.

That is class has a polymorphic association with a few other classes (`cmodal`, `umodal`, `ccmodal`, `pmodal`, `emodal`)

The creation of `rmodal` has a form with a hidden field that include its type (`cmodal`, `umodal`, etc) and its ID (`r_id`)

Is the following code sufficiently secured? brakeman currently notes that this line could result in remote code exectuion

```
 @r_type = params[:r].delete :r_type

 if (%w(cmodal umodal ccmodal pmodal emodal).include? @r_type)

      @rmodal = @r_type.classify.constantize.find(@r_id) rescue nil
```

I am guessing, that since I am checking that `r_type` is one of the acceptable choices that it is fine.

Is this the right way to do this and is it secure enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are limiting the input to a whitelist of known values, I would consider this secure. Brakeman currently cannot tell that you are using a guard statement, so it warns about turning user input (`params[:r]`) into a class name, but in this case I would consider it a false positive.